# React NavLink: Capture dynamic Routes but onClick redirect to a specific route

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

My NavLink Route looks as follows:

```
<NavLink
            key={element.id}
            to={element.uri || '/'}
            className={classes.NavBarElements}
            activeStyle={element.activeStyle || preDefinedActiveStyle}>
            {icon} <p className={classes.TagElement}>{element.label}</p>
          </NavLink>
```

Now element object looks like:

```
 config: {
    id: nanoid(),
    label: 'Connect & Mix',
    uri: '/config/metadata',
    action_id: 'level0__config',
    action_state: {},
  }
```

Now what I desire is that `element.uri` should have a route like this: `/config/:configType` where `:configType` can be anything from an array of strings (`configTypesArray`), but onClick to that tab it should move to the specific `:configType` which is the first element of `configTypesArray`. I am not sure on how to achieve the same.

routing array looks like below:

`configTypesArray = ['metadata','datastream','nodatastream']`

if user goes to any other route beyond what is listed, I am interested in showing a simple page with `<div>Page Not Found</div>`.

React Router version: `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`